# PassportJS / NodeJS secure REST API with Google Auth

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have an application that uses passport with [passport-google-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth) to allow Google Authentication with RESTful API endpoints.

I'm looking to create other applications (for example, a Chrome extension) that need to communicate with these API endpoints. How do I secure a REST API with Google authentication in passport? I read a lot of things on securing a REST API in general (i.e. if I had my own login), but how would I do it if my application relies on a third-party login? (ie. Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.)

Thanks

Comment: Can you share with us, how you used passport-google-oauth to allow Google Authentication with RESTful API endpoints?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Passport.js *ONLY* handles authentication -- it doesn't handle authorization at all.

What you'll want to do, if you want to authenticate a user to your webapp is use something like Google Oauth to let a user create an account on your webapp.

You'll then need to use a separate Passport.js strategy for handling developer authentication against *your* API service.

For instance, if you want a developer to authenticate against your API using Basic Auth, you could use this Passport strategy to allow this: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http

Hopefully that makes sense!